# Swift 2 parsing and reading JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift2

I'm new to Swift 2.0 but I have experience in OOP languages. I'm trying to display just a name of the city in a label via JSON API. But I constantly get the error "EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION" and "Unwrapping nil" error. I assume that the problem maybe is in the URL. Because I've tried with another API, radnomuser.me/api and I get the result with no errors. Can someone lead me to solution because I get so much answers on the internet and all of them are different. If You didn't understood my problem, feel free to ask, because I think this is a crucial part.
Thanks!

```
@IBOutlet weak var viaSegueTextView: UITextView!{

var viaSegue = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    getWeatherData()



}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
func getWeatherData {
     let endpoint = NSURL(string: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=44db6a862fba0b067b1930da0d769e98")
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: endpoint!)

    do {
      if let json: NSDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary {
             if let name = json["name"] as? String
            {

                    viaSegueLabel.text = "\(name)"

            }
        }
    }catch let error as NSError{
        print("\(error)")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Parsing and reading is fine. Your `viaSegueLabel` is nil. I tried your download/parse snippet in Playground and it parsed well. Also for next time - don't **EVER** post your app id's, login names etc...

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it's just test app, just reading JSON and displaying data, but I understand what You mean. 
I still don't get it. I know that I have nil, that means that I didn't got value form the JSON. For some reason it stops just before the "if", viaSequeLabel is nil because it didn't parse it or because the URL is wrong or something else?
Thanks for the respond.

Comment: It's not the issue, but `JSONObjectWithData` does not return an optional so the optional binding is useless. Write `let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: []) as! [String:AnyObject]`, if an error occurs the catch block will be executed

Comment: @vadian Can u recommend me what should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import Foundation

func getWeatherData() {
    guard let endpoint = NSURL(string: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=44db6a862fba0b067b1930da0d769e98"),
        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: endpoint) else { return }

    do {
        if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary {
            if let name = json["name"] as? String {
                print(name) // London
            }
        }
    } catch let error as NSError{
        print("\(error)")
    }
}
getWeatherData() // prints
// London
```

Answer (score 1):

- First of all, you must link your IBOutlet in InterfaceBuilder. That can be the first point where you can get the unwrapping nil error.
- Second point, viewDidLoad is a method on a view controller, I don't understand why your brackets after UITextView.
- Third, there is no viaSegueLabel declared in your code.
- Fourth, try to not force unwrap so many optionals (use !) and use if let instead.
- For a first iteration I would change the getWeatherData method like this:

  ```
  func getWeatherData() {
      let endpoint = NSURL(string: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=44db6a862fba0b067b1930da0d769e98")
      if let endpoint = endpoint, data = NSData(contentsOfURL: endpoint) {
          do {
              if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary {
                  if let name = json["name"] as? String
                  {
                      print(name)
                  }
              }
          } catch let error as NSError{
              print("\(error)")
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Sorry for the wrong variable declaration, viaSegueLabel is an outlet and it is declared but I wrote it incorrectly. I've tried not force it, but the Xcode forces me to do it like that.
Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

SWIFT 3

func WeatherData() 
{
        guard let endpoint = NSURL(string: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=44db6a862fba0b067b1930da0d769e98"),
            let data = NSData(contentsOf: endpoint as URL) else { return }

```
    do {
        if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data as Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary {
            if let weather = json["weather"] as? NSDictionary {
                print(weather) // London
            }
        }
    } catch let error as NSError{
        print("\(error)")
    }
}
```